# doctrine in combination with TranslationWalker generates too many queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation

I have multilingual project and I use symfony2+doctrine.

If I try to display list of objects in language different than the default one, doctrine generates one query to get all data for all objects and then generates one query for every single object, witch is unnecessary.

The code in the repository code looks like:

```
$repository = $this->_em->getRepository($this->_entityName);
$keywordController = new \Cms\Bundles\KeywordBundle\Controller\ObjectKeywordController();
    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $queryBuilder->andWhere('e.status=:status');
    $queryBuilder->setParameter('status', 'public');
    $queryBuilder->andWhere('e.displayTranslation = :displayTranslation');
    $queryBuilder->setParameter('displayTranslation', 'true');

    $queryBuilder->orderBy('e.publishedDate', 'DESC');

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
    $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');

    if ($locale) {
        $query->setHint(\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, $locale);
    }
    $paginator = new Paginator($query);

    $total_items = count($paginator);
    $pages_count = (int) ceil($total_items / $page_row_count);


    // now get one page's items:
    $paginator
            ->getQuery()
            ->setFirstResult($page_row_count * ($current_page - 1)) // set the offset
            ->setMaxResults($page_row_count); // set the limit
```

I and get the following queries:

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id_0, t1_.content AS title_1, t2_.content AS sub_title_2, t3_.content AS announce_3, t4_.content AS author_4, t5_.content AS content_5, t6_.content AS source_6, a0_.creation_date AS creation_date_7, a0_.update_date AS update_date_8, a0_.published_date AS published_date_9, a0_.schedule_disable_date AS schedule_disable_date_10, a0_.schedule_publish_date AS schedule_publish_date_11, t7_.content AS seo_title_12, t8_.content AS seo_description_13, t9_.content AS keywords_as_text_14, t10_.content AS main_pic_description_15, t11_.content AS main_pic_title_16, t12_.content AS slug_17, t13_.content AS status_18, t14_.content AS display_translation_19, a0_.comments_enabled AS comments_enabled_20, t15_.content AS comments_count_21, a0_.main_pic AS main_pic_22, a0_.poll_id AS poll_id_23, a0_.attachment_id AS attachment_id_24, a0_.gallery_id AS gallery_id_25, a0_.created_by AS created_by_26, a0_.main_category_id AS main_category_id_27 FROM articles a0_ LEFT JOIN article_translations t1_ ON t1_.locale = 'bg' AND t1_.field = 'title' AND t1_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t2_ ON t2_.locale = 'bg' AND t2_.field = 'subTitle' AND t2_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t3_ ON t3_.locale = 'bg' AND t3_.field = 'announce' AND t3_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t4_ ON t4_.locale = 'bg' AND t4_.field = 'author' AND t4_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t5_ ON t5_.locale = 'bg' AND t5_.field = 'content' AND t5_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t6_ ON t6_.locale = 'bg' AND t6_.field = 'source' AND t6_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t7_ ON t7_.locale = 'bg' AND t7_.field = 'seoTitle' AND t7_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t8_ ON t8_.locale = 'bg' AND t8_.field = 'seoDescription' AND t8_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t9_ ON t9_.locale = 'bg' AND t9_.field = 'keywordsAsText' AND t9_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t10_ ON t10_.locale = 'bg' AND t10_.field = 'mainPicDescription' AND t10_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t11_ ON t11_.locale = 'bg' AND t11_.field = 'mainPicTitle' AND t11_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t12_ ON t12_.locale = 'bg' AND t12_.field = 'slug' AND t12_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t13_ ON t13_.locale = 'bg' AND t13_.field = 'status' AND t13_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t14_ ON t14_.locale = 'bg' AND t14_.field = 'displayTranslation' AND t14_.object_id = a0_.id LEFT JOIN article_translations t15_ ON t15_.locale = 'bg' AND t15_.field = 'commentsCount' AND t15_.object_id = a0_.id WHERE t13_.content = 'public' AND t14_.content = 'true' AND a0_.id IN ('176448', '176447', '176446', '176444', '176442', '176441', '176440', '176437', '176436', '176435', '176434', '176424') ORDER BY a0_.published_date DESC;
```

and the for every object a query like:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.locale AS locale_2, t0.field AS field_3, t0.content AS content_4, t0.object_id AS object_id_5 FROM article_translations t0 WHERE t0.object_id = ?
```

How to avoid this extra queries and why doctrine don't use the data from the first one?

Note: All extra queries are generated in function postLoad in the TranslatableListener class. There is a parameter $skipOnLoad, which is always false, and it looks like this is somehow the problem, but why this happens I have no idea:)